# Shared pointer of a class inside a class referenced by a shared pointer gives error when trying to perform shared_from_this

Tags: c++, boost

This is my class structure:

```cpp
class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
}

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
    shared_ptr<B> b_;
    void SomeFunction();
}
```

I'm getting an error on this line:

```cpp
void A::SomeFunction() {
    auto a_copy = shared_from_this();
}
```

The error text is:

`error: no matching member function for call to 'shared_from_this'`

When I remove the `shared_ptr<B> b_;` line from class A everything works fine..
I'm guessing that there are some requirements on the object I'm trying to `enable_shared_from_this` on, but I tried all sorts of things and searched for the error message but to no avail..

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You don't need [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) to create a shared pointer of an object. Only if you need to actually create a shared pointer from `this`. Do `B` really need to inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`?

Comment: As for your problem, with a little fixes your code [builds and I can't replicate the build error](https://ideone.com/rHBVRR). It doesn't run, but at least it builds. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Thanks, while trying to build the example I figured out the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a little embarrassing..
The problem was that I wrote `shared_ptr<B> b_` instead of `std::shared_ptr<B> b_`. My IDE (Android Studio) didn't highlight this error in the editor, and also in the build output it didn't present the error with a link to that line, so I just skipped that line and saw only the following bug, which of course stated that there is no such function for this unknown type. I guess I got too used to the convenience of the IDE :)

Leaving this here in case someone else misses this..